# How to get a value of arbitrary property in Maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I want to get a value of a Maven project property from inside my plugin. The name of the property I'm getting in runtime (not in compile-time) and it's not defined in `<properties>`, thus can't use Plexus injections. How I can do it otherwise?

Comment: Are you getting it via command line `-D`?

Comment: Not really, in my case it's `${project.name}`, but can be anything else, including the ones specified in command line with `-D`

Comment: I removed my answer since it obviously cannot be applied in your situation. What about simple `System.getProperty()`?

Comment: `System.getProperty("project.name")`? you think it will work? :)

Answer (score -1):

In your plugin, if you have a field with the following annotation:

```
@Parameter( property="my.cli.property", defaultValue="${project.name}" )
private String commandLineParam;
```

This would fill in the project's `<name/>` by default, but allow people to override from the command line using `-Dmy.cli.property=value`. If you don't want to allow overrides from the command line, you can leave off the `property` parameter of this `@Parameter` annotation. If you don't have a default value you want to use, but instead want users to supply their own value from the command line each time, you can leave off the `defaultValue` parameter. If some value is required, you can set the `required` parameter to `true`.

For more information, see: [Maven Plugin Annotations](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/index.html).

For an example of this in action, see: [Parameter declarations in the install-file mojo](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/blob/trunk/maven-install-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/install/InstallFileMojo.java#L68%20Install-File%20Mojo%20Parameters)

Comment: -1. Please read the question carefully. I know the name of the property only in **runtime**, not in compile time.

Comment: Discussion of properties in 'runtime' vs. 'compile-time' doesn't really make sense. These are dependency scopes... Are you talking about resolving the value as a plugin executes instead of when the pom.xml is parsed? If so, try injecting a MavenProject instance using `${project}` then you *might* be able to pull the properties from that and get the value you want.

Comment: How exactly I can pull the properties from `MavenProject`?

Comment: @Parameter( defaultValue="${project}" ) MavenProject project...then later, project.getProperties()

Comment: `getProperties()` returns only properties defined in `<properties>` section of `pom.xml`. `${project.name}` won't be there.

Comment: so you want a Properties object with all of the key/values available during parameter injection? Surely you can see how it's confusing what you're asking for. Maybe if you provide a specific use case it would help clear things up.